# How to cause a postback of the Parent page from an UpdatePanel?

Tags: updatepanel, postback, parent

I have a LinkButton which is in a Panel that contains an UpdatePanel. When clicked, the only thing that happens is the Panel closes. I need to do a postback to the parent page. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not set EnablePartialRendering to false when somebody clicks on the linkbutton causing it do a full postback and then later inthe code you can set it back to true?

Comment: I don't get it. Where do I set that property?

Comment: the ScriptManager control's EnablePartialRending property is set to True. This indicates that the page supports partial-page updates. You can use this property to turn this feature off if needed.